# First setup of iPhone SE without WiFi and iTunes

Tags: itunes, iphone, ios

Suppose the situation you bought iPhone SE in an area where is no WiFi (or you need to tell the iPhone's MAC address to the system administrator first) and you do not have a computer at all.
How to get through the first setup wizard?

Comment: It has a SIM card inside. Do you have cellular coverage?

Comment: Put the phone away for a couple of weeks.

Comment: You could point out to the admin that MAC address ‘security’ gets less useful every year & that iPhones present a random address to any Wi-Fi they’re not specifically told otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

iPhones require a connection in order to set up, because the set up process requires the phone check in with Apple, even if it isn't set up on a carrier yet.

You can either use the carrier (if you have an active SIM), WiFi, or a computer. If you don't have any of these there is not a way to set up the device.

Comment: That is a control on your Wi-Fi, and your Wi-Fi router should be able to tell you the iPhone's Mac address.

Comment: Nowhere. I'm providing more information that MIGHT be valuable, or it could further illustrate that you will have to wait for one of these several options you currently do not have access to is available before you'll be able to use your phone.

Comment: Look, I'm not arguing with you. You came here for information, we gave you information making assumptions to fill in parts you didn't specify. You can do the same. You can also follow the methods of this site and mark my answer as correct because, despite it not being the information you want, it is the correct information you requested we give you.